# Cordova video player not working

Tags: angularjs, apache, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I installed the plugin correctly following the tutorials and even the documentation, but whenever I present my account through DEVAPP, I get a message:

"console.warn: Native: tried calling VideoPlayer.play, but the VideoPlayer plugin is not installed. console.warn: Install the VideoPlayer plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add
            https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer.git'

I do not really know what might be causing this error as I installed it and I can see in installed plugins. But when I try to run the application, it says it is not installed. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Remove node_modules and install again that might be helpful.

Comment: How do I do this? This folder has many files, it already installs all of them again?